# Mostrar datos de una consulta correctamente en una vista blade de laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Realizo una consulta en una vista de blade pero no me muestra los datos correctamente, En la imagen podeis ver que problema tengo

```
@foreach (Cart::instance('compare')->content() as $item)
 <td class="description">
 <p>                                         
    {{App\Product::select("short_description")->where('id', $item- >id)->get()}}
 </p>
</td><!-- /.description -->
@endforeach
```

[image: na consu]

Answer (score 2):

Lo que acabas de hacer es una burrada. Las consultas en una vista ralentizan muchisimo, ademas de que no usas eager o lazy load

En tu modelo de Cart, deberías tener una relación con products

```
 public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'id', 'id');
    }
```

En el controlador deberías hacer la consulta

```
Cart::instance('compare')->with('product')->content()
```

Y en la vista

```
$cart->product->short_description
```